# Is web.config protected by IIS?

Tags: security, iis, web-config

I'm looking for details on web.config (encrypting it is OK).
My question is : 
Does IIS natively protect this file (as an exception rule to NEVER deliver it through http whatever the security rights)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, IIS will not return "*.config" files by default. You can/should also [encrypt them](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx) as well though.

Comment: This is a default in the metabase for IIS6 and I assume the same setting exists in IIS7x

Answer (score 0):

IIS is anyways not going to serve a web.config or any .config file. Its a protected file as you rightly mention in your question.